# Action bar tabs - how to retrieve value from fragments in Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I've settings activity, which has 3 tabs (each tab contains fragment) + in the main activity there is also buttons row - with buttons OK, and Cancel.When I press OK, I would like to do something like this:

1) get all my custom variables from all fragments
2) save them to shared prefs

But how to get access to fragment variables? I tried this:

Adding tabs in main activity:

```
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionbar.newTab().setText(res.getString(R.string.actSettingsTab1));
    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(new Tab1Fragment(), "tab1"));
    actionbar.addTab(tab1);
    //...similar for all tabs
```

This is my tab listener:

```
class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment fragment;
    private String tag;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
```

And this is how I would like to get variables from fragments:

```
Tab1Fragment tab1 = (Tab1Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("tab1");
Tab2Fragment tab2 = (Tab1Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("tab2");
Tab3Fragment tab3 = (Tab1Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("tab3");
```

but it's strange - findFragmentByTag returns fragment only for selected tab, otherwise returns null. So when I have selected tab1 and press ok, findFragmentByTag return fragment for tab1, but null for others.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or whole my tring is goind wrong way. How to retrieve values from all fragments in parent activity and save them to shared preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the process into two steps:

1) Gather all settings from all the fragments in real time (i.e. as they are changed by the user). Use Listener pattern, so that fragments will expose an interface by which they will notify attached listener when user modifies any of the settings for which given fragment is responsible for. Let the activity attach itself as a listener to all fragments, and capture changes (store them in a structure that suits you).

2) Let the activity save settings using SharedPreferences when OK button is clicked. It does not have to access fragments as it always about any settings user has changed.

This way you do not have to access all the fragments at once, which is impossible if they are removed from the memory (as they are not visible anyway at a given time). Instead, you can re-assign the activity as a listener to selected fragment every time it gets selected/displayed.

Comment: good point. Thanks...Btw, I just started with fragments but seriously...Don't you think, they make code much harder to read (instead of easier) because you must think to always save everything when fragment state changes, implement listeners to communicate with parent activity etc...My code is maybe 1/3 larger than without fragments + harder to understand. And of course, docs to fragments is not very good - it doesn't cover many things :(

Comment: At first I felt that way as well. But once you'll get used to doing things slightly different, you'll see they provide you higher code reusability. It depends of course on how you design your fragments, and it takes some practice to get most of this concept. Take it easy, read a lot and keep asking questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend actually accessing the variables from your fragments.  You could make a public method in those fragments that does the shared preferences saving that you want.  Ex:

```
Tab1Fragment tab1 = (Tab1Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("tab1");
Tab2Fragment tab2 = (Tab1Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("tab2");
Tab3Fragment tab3 = (Tab1Fragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("tab3");
tab1.savePreferences();
tab2.savePreferences();
tab3.savePreferences();
```

Comment: good idea. However, main problem is, that for 2 of 3 tabs findFragmentByTag returns always null (except selected one)

Comment: User `ft.detach(fragment);` in the `onTabUnselected()` method in your listener instead of `ft.remove(...)`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionbar.newTab().setText(res.getString(R.string.actSettingsTab1));
> tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(new Tab1Fragment(), "tab1"));
> actionbar.addTab(tab1);
> //...similar for all tabs
> ```

this does not add your Fragment to the backstack therefore you get only the selected tab and the others are null.

I think the best you can do is iterate through the tabs of the ActionBar using **getTabCount()** and then you should be able to get your content with **getTabAt(int index).    getCustomView()**